# Apache Tomcat: "Context variable"

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm new to Tomcat and hence have a few question. I want to have certain objects available for my Context from any code. I was able to achieve this for a DataSource because that is the example used in the Tomcat guide.

I would like to add 2 additional objects:
Object A that uses this DataSource in the Constructor
Object B that uses Object A in it's constructor

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's probably the easiest thing to do is use a `ContextListener` that inserts Objects A and B into the Context. See http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Servlets4.html for a usage example: in the `contextInitialized` method you can grab the datasource out of the context, create objects A and B and then store them back into the context.

Comment: I assume with "store them back into the context" you mean context.bind? I tried that and it results in an exception. "Googling" revealed tomcat context is read-only. So this does not work.

Comment: `context.setAttribute` (see http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) is the method you want. You can then get them out with `context.getAttribute` (see http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29). Take a look at the javadoc: its often the easiest way to figure out what tools are available to you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Tomcat 5.5 spec. found on http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/globalresources.html I see that `Context` is not capable of doing such tricks and is not  for such usages.

You'd like to have some objects available from "any code". If this any is confined to a single web application, than you can consider **@Fermi**'s answer or maybe you should launch a Spring `ApplicationContext`. That might sound a bit too difficult if you're not familiar with Spring Framework yet, however if you keep developing your application I think there will be a certain point where things start to become easier if a Spring context already exists from the beginning. (Tell me in a comment if you need help with setting up Spring provided you choose that way.)